# Changing onTintColor of UISwitch on iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiswitch

Default `onTintColor` is green as I see it on iOS7 but I'd like it to be another color.

```
[myUISwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor customColor]];
```

does not work. `on/offImages` have no effect on iOS7 as documentation says. Why could it be not working? How can I change its `onTintColor`?

Comment: Setting the `onTintColor` works for me. Are you sure `myUISwitch` isn't `nil` when you make the call?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
UISwitch *switch = [UISwitch alloc] init];
[switch setOnTintColor:[UIColor customColor]];
[myView addSubview:switch];
```

does not work. But

```
UISwitch *switch = [UISwitch alloc] init];
[myView addSubview:switch];
[switch setOnTintColor:[UIColor customColor]];
```

works. Tint color does not change unless it is visible. Someone to explain?

Comment: After you call alloc and init, the switch's view hierarchy is not fully initialized until you show it and viewDidLoad: is called.

Comment: Ugh, that is so annoying. I really wonder what goes on at Apple sometimes.

Comment: There's the `thumbTintColor` property as well if you're looking to change that.

Comment: For Swift this still holds true. Setting it in awakeFromNib for a cell has no effect; you have to set it in layoutSubviews or somewhere else that it called _after_ the switch is added